# .waitForXPath only works after mouse hover over element (rendered page)

Tags: javascript, puppeteer, salesforce-lightning

I have the following Puppeteer code:

```
await pageSF.goto('SalesForcePage');
pageSF.waitForNavigation({waitUntil: 'networkidle2'});
await pageSF.waitForXPath("//span[@id='window' and text()='SFDC Admin']");
```

To find the following span in a Salesforce lightning page:

```
<span force-lookup_lookup="" data-proxy-id="aura-pos-lib-1" id="window">SFDC Admin</span>
```

I've been trying to figure out for hours why the selector doesn't find anything, but then noticed that if I run puppeteer with `{headless: false}`, the selector finds the span if I hover over the span with the mouse cursor or interact with it manually in any way.

I'm pretty sure this has to do with how Salesforce Lightning renders the content on the pages, but how do I let the selector find the element without any manual intervention? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I added a `mouse.move` line with the coordinates of where the element is on the page before the `waitForXPath`and now it finds the element, but I wonder if there is a less butchered approach to this.

Comment: I have classic saleforce automation using puppeteer; now I need to switch to lightning and it looks like hell; any successes Gregory?